# Firebug shows a class name and its location twice in right panel

Tags: html, css, firebug

When i inspect a div with class `.mlm-clearfix`, firebug shows this class name and its url twice in right panel. The style declarations of Easy Clear Method given for the class is

```
.mlm-clearfix:before,
.mlm-clearfix:after {
   content: '\0020';
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   visibility: hidden;
   width: 0;
   height: 0; 
}
```

When i removed one selector and modified it to

```
.mlm-clearfix:after {
   content: '\0020';
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   visibility: hidden;
   width: 0;
   height: 0; 
}
```

issue disappears. But this is not happening to other combined class selectors like

```
.search-table td input,
.search-table td select {
    width: 200px;
}
```

css file is not linked twice. What could be the reason for this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:before` and `:after` are [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements). (The correct syntax for them is actually `::before` and `::after`). Selectors containing them don't style the selected element itself but define new elements, which will be styled.

The [Firefox API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/inIDOMUtils#getCSSStyleRules%28%29) Firebug (2.0.x) internally [uses](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/962d82bd1d31171a39a57aa7f5b14da8e1d164a3/extension/content/firebug/css/stylePanel.js#L287) only allows to get all styles for a given pseudo-element. Though Firebug doesn't check whether there is already the same rule for another pseudo-element. So the rule will be displayed twice within the [*Style* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Style_Side_Panel).

This issue will be solved as soon as these pseudo-elements are displayed within the HTML structure inside the [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel) instead of the *Style* side panel (see [issue 5785](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5785)).